# Rspec View test model stub variable not passing to the view for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got below code passing my model variable to the view

```
describe "payslips/index.html.erb" do
  it "should display the page" do
    assign(:income_tax_rates, [
        stub_model(IncomeTaxRate.all)
    ])

    render

    puts rendered
    # expect(rendered).to include()
  end
end
```

Then I have this:

```
<% @income_tax_rates.each do |tax_rate| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= number_to_currency tax_rate[:income_from], :precision => 0 %></td>
                        <td><%= number_to_currency tax_rate[:income_to], :precision => 0 %></td>
                        <td><%= tax_rate[:start] %></td>
                        <td><%= tax_rate[:finish] %></td>
                        <td><%= tax_rate[:rate] %></td>
                        <td><%= number_to_currency tax_rate[:premium], :precision => 0 %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% end %>
```

But this does not seem to be generating anything instead I get empty `td`s

What could I do to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSpec's `stub_model` expects a constant as an argument such as an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass used to define a model. It also expects either additional parameters or a block in order to set the values of the instance of the class.

You've passed in an `ActiveModel::Relation`, which is the result of a the `all`, and even if you'd provided the expected class constant, you haven't provided any parameter values.

See the examples for how this is intended to be used at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/mocks/stub-model